# Storing Map Canvas (current view) so it may be recalled and restored later using QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, mapcanvas

Is there any way in QGIS3 to save "settings" for the current map canvas/view so the very same view can be restored later?

Comment: You might look at map themes and bookmarks.

Comment: Bookmarks bring back the same location, but do not reconstruct the view.

Comment: From the documentation, a map theme is a snapshot of "the legend", that is the list of layers.  "A map theme does not remember the current details of the properties..."

Answer (score 1):

I looked into the QGIS API and created a PyQGIS script to:

1. create a log file saving the relevant parameters needed to restore the mapCanvas/view, and simultaneously to:
2. create an actual PyQGIS script to do the restoration.

What follows is an example of the second, restoration, script--auto-generated by the first, "save", script. You can use it as-is, substituting your previously noted values.

I copy/paste the commands from either script into a Python Console window (Plugins->PythonConsole) to execute them because I haven't yet figured out how to run an external script from the console.

I am not a Python gnoscent, but a hacker in the classic sense. I look at code examples and without diving too deeply, hack something together to see if it will work.

```
#This script is named: # /media/Projects1/Project_M459/ \
#/PyQGISscript_reconstruct-qgis-canvas-view-of-
#Project_M459.py #It was created by: 
# PyQGIS_save-qgis-canvas-view-data-to-file.py

#To reconstruct the orig. view, reconstruct the conditions;
#  e.g., simply copy/paste these commands into the PyQGIS console window):
#        to restore the canvas to the way it was when it was saved:
# BEWARE: python does not like leading indents nor, apparently trailing comments
#
# attach to the iface
canvas=qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas()
# set window size
ssz=QSize(726,625)
canvas.resize(ssz)
# set center point
scp=QgsPointXY(705789.0114976235,509277.4794886983)
canvas.setCenter(scp)
# set XY extents
sex=QgsRectangle(702646.6503865124,506573.48643314274,\
708931.3726087346,511981.47254425386)
canvas.setExtent(sex)
# set magnification factor/zoom (before setting scale)
smf=1.0
canvas.setMagnificationFactor(smf)
# set window scale factor
ssc=10000.00000000004
canvas.zoomScale(ssc)
#
#Note: if sz, sc, and either ex or cp are set, the remaining one should follow.
#      however they are set here individually as well.
```

Comment: You requested no edits to your Q&A but I think you are trying to depart from the site protocols much too far to leave it as-is.  In particular, there was considerable commentary included that distracts from the focused Q&A performed here on the Main site.

Comment: By removing it, you also removed people's ability to judge your personal interpretation of "considerable" and "commentary" both.  I requested it to be left as it was, based on this, stackoverflow, reference[1] which suggested to me that authors were entitled to have their posts respected. You chose not to respect my post.[1] https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/03/04/the-great-edit-wars/

Comment: The technical content of your post, which self-answered your question, was respected.

Comment: Thank you for proving my point. Respect is reserved for technical content, not authors/contributors. (We are actually not bots out here.)